# как получить список всех файлов в папке на Java

Tags: java

Подскажите как получить список файлов в папке, вот код:

```
File dir = new File(path); //path указывает на директорию
File[] arrFiles = dir.listFiles();
List<File> lst = Arrays.asList(arrFiles);
```

но он добавляет не только файлы, а и директории в этой папке
А есть метод (или готовое решение) который выдает только файлы?

Answer (score 2):

```
File dir = new File(path); //path указывает на директорию
List<File> lst = new ArrayList<>();
for ( File file : dir.listFiles() ){
    if ( file.isFile() )
        lst.add(file);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вообще *File#listFiles* себя не очень показывает (медленный), лучше как-то так:

```
Files.walk(Paths.get("/path/to/folder"))
 .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
 .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Answer (score 0):

Я делал что-то такое когда-то:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.io.File;


public class Files {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            File currentDir = new File("d:/tmp");
            displayAllFilesDirectories(currentDir);

        }

    // Отображение все файлов и папок основной дирректории
        public static void displayAllFilesDirectories(File dir) {
            try {
                File[] files = dir.listFiles();
                for (File file : files) {
                    if (file.isDirectory()) {
                        System.out.println("directory: " + file.getCanonicalPath());
    // Вывести файлы подкаталогов, ежели нужно: displayAllFilesDirectories(file);
            } else {

    // Форматирование даты изменения файла с миллисекунд на адекватную
            long lastModified = file.lastModified();
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");

            System.out.println("     file: " + file.getCanonicalPath() + ", размер файла: "
                    + file.length() + " byte, дата изменения: " + sdf.format(new Date(lastModified)));

                            }
                        }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```